# How can I use the contents of a file, and each line of another file as arguments in a bash script, for a command line tool?

Tags: shell-script, security, kali-linux, john-the-ripper

I have viewed the other questions which, were helpful, but do not answer my problem.
I am trying to write a script that can assist me with college work*. I have a file containing a hash which through, "trial and error" needs to be cracked to get the final answer. The instructions specifically require jtr jumbo edition, so the list of possible formats is large. I passed all the available formats to a file called "johnformats" that contain the formats 1 per line. I want this script to run like:

> $ john hash.txt --format=[cat line 1 from johnformats] > johnout

then repeat through last format value

> $ john hash.txt --format=[cat line 204 from johnformats] > johnout

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

johnformats=$1
johnout=$2

exec 4> "$johnout"

while read -ru 3 LINE; do
    john "$(cat hash.txt)" --format="$LINE" >&4
done 3< "$johnformats"
```

When run using script the hash does not load:

> stat: cat hash: No such file or directory

I have tried the following removing the $hash altogether to see if any of it works:

> Password files required, but none specified

repeat 204 times telling me the other part works, but

john the ripper syntax requires the hash(s) from a file.

I just need to figure out how to get it to use the contents of "hash," for each $LINE.

*note my question is not how to crack it, it is how to write a script for the tool I am using to crack it. Scripting is encouraged, but not required,and has nothing to do with the assignment. I have not memorized every possible hash prefix, and this will save me from carpel tunnel.

Comment: Try `john -format="$LINE" hash.txt >&4`. And make sure the hash.txt file actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the reason for the added complexity. What you actually want is:

```
john hash.txt --format=[cat line 1 from johnformats] > johnout
john hash.txt --format=[cat line 2 from johnformats] >> johnout
john hash.txt --format=[cat line 3 from johnformats] >> johnout
```

etcetera.

So, in a script, that would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

johnformats=$1
johnout=$2

while read line ; do
    john hash.txt --format="$line" >>$johnout
done < $johnformats
```

There should be no need to add the complecity of the addtional filedescriptors 3 and 4, and the `"$(cat hash.txt)"` does something completely different then adding `hash.txt` as an argument.

Ofcourse, the error message suggests that `hash` is used as argument, not `hash.txt` that is in the code above, and in also suggests that the file `hash` does not exist. Those are things that you want to check too.

Comment: Thank you. As I work out problems, I have noticed instead of simplifying I want to complicate things further. I must break this habit somehow.